# In Swift how to insert new object of entity

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, entity

I am new to CoreData and apologize in advance if the question is difficult to understand. So... Assuming we have two entities - Cars and Items (one to many relationship). I have 2 objects in cars (let§s say... BMW and Audi) and want to add a new item to Audi. How to select the Audi entity in which to add new item object? I know how to add new instance of item, but how to associate them to the specific entity... let say of Audi?

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Cars", in: context)
let newItem = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context) as! Item
newItem.type = "Oil"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Item entity should have a relationship for the car it belongs to. To set the car that the item belongs to, set the variable for the car in the relationship, something similar to the following:

```
newItem.car = selectedCar // The Audi in your example.
```

Your app's interface has a table view or some other view to select cars. When someone selects a car from the list, store the selected car in a variable and use that to set the item's car.

Without more information about your Car and Item entities and your app's user interface, I cannot provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I think understand you. But i have an another question. Car entities was populated in a tableview (Audi, Bmw... cells). How to proceed to achieve when tap on an Audi cell, Audi's items added to it to be populated in an another tableview? Its a bit hard for me as i am a very new :) with coreData

Comment: Your followup question is more of a general iOS development question than a Core Data question. I recommend going through a general iOS development book or video course to learn the basics of iOS development. The following link contains resources for learning iOS development: [Learning iOS Development](https://www.swiftdevjournal.com/learning-ios-development/)